# Is it possible to dynamically generate classes, in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, dynamic, schema

One of the implication would generating data structure using schemas, i.e. XML or JSON. That would simplify the process of dev especially when the schema is not known before it is received, i.e. fetch from a remote location.

I looked at similar question like this: [Is it possible to dynamically generate a class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567736/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-generate-a-class-in-net).